# On which site can I ask about the initial specifications of rotor blades for a ducted fan?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have questions on the subject of turbomachinery -- axial compressor theory. Specifically the initial specification of stagger angle, camber angle solidity etc. of the rotor blades for a ducted fan.

Where can I ask my questions?

Answer (score 10):

**Engineering.**

There are many questions on the subject of fans, ducting, torque, the addition of static-blades, propeller-shape etc. on our [Engineering site](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions).

The available tags would include [thrust](/questions/tagged/thrust), [fluid-mechanics](/questions/tagged/fluid-mechanics), [aerodynamics](/questions/tagged/aerodynamics), [airflow](/questions/tagged/airflow) and many others that can be seen [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=ducted+fan). You may find that a more specific search (top of the page there) than that one reveals that the answers you seek are already provided to an existing question.

You will also find that our [Aviation site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=fan+duct) may provide some helpful insight into the issues you face.